# Omit needless spaces for me

Tags: code-golf, python

A great Python golfing tip is to [omit needless spaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87181/88546). But if you are like me, you don't always have the time to search for which spaces to remove. If only there was a way to speed up the process...

### Task

Given a *single line* of Python, as input, return/output a new line which omits all needless spaces. The table below shows which spaces are *needless*, and must be removed for *maximum golfage*.

```
   | L D S
---+-------
 L | s s n
 D | n - n
 S | n n n

First token is row, second token is column
L: Letter
D: Digit
S: Symbol

s: space
n: no space
-: never happens (except multidigit numbers)
```

### Clarifications

- What is considered a letter, digit, and symbol?

  - Letter: `_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
  - Digit: `0123456789`
  - Symbol: `` !"\#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ``
- You can assume that all characters in the input are either a *Letter*, *Digit*, *Symbol*, or *Space*.
- You can assume that there will be no such test case where two digits are separated by *one or more* spaces
- You can assume that all test cases contain valid Python syntax
- You can assume that there will be no leading or trailing spaces.
- Follow the above rules for omitting spaces, regardless of whether omitting them will produce incorrect or different code

### Test Cases

#### Input

```py
print ( "Hello, World!" )
eval("eval('eval(`1`)')")
_  =  '_  =  %  r  ;  print _  %%  _'  ;  print _  %  _
[ 1for _ in range(10, 6 , -1)     ]
print 16
```

#### Output

```py
print("Hello,World!")
eval("eval('eval(`1`)')")
_='_=%r;print _%%_';print _%_
[1for _ in range(10,6,-1)]
print 16
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Related fact: you can delete any space after a complex number literal (which ends with `j`); Python tokenizes e.g. `1jfor` (`1j for`) and `1jor` (`1j or`) without problem.

Comment: *You can assume that all characters in the input are either a Letter, Digit, or Symbol* - for completeness you may want to add *Space*. Code that does nothing is valid otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Now clarified that there will be no leading or trailing spaces in test cases.

Comment: Nice problem, but would have been much more fun if we had to skip strings.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to a mysterious hint from @Neil :P*

```
(\d|\W) +
$1
 (\W)
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BCsIwELznFWOwJMEK5iIU8e4PerCSBholEJISiif/HrepB/cwOzs7O2x2i4@2FDlMn6FXOLC9ZpBEiZQyZx8XQALgwM2FkFrifcph2nEo5t42SF5RVMQIjVEJcimumAGugNhaA2TgAvxiqWjRkGzEn26q07A79DNlGn1crdnGl5P6tD5wRoujVjXiwbazrvsC)

Comment: I can actually shave a byte off that... I'll keep you in suspense for a bit.

Comment: I think @Neil should just randomly post that exact comment on people's answers (with no idea in mind) just to inspire them :D

Comment: @GregMartin Eerie, as I had a completely different idea in mind anyway. I like his approach though, since the first stage ensures that there are no runs of spaces remaining.

Comment: I like his/her approach as well (and the attribution phrasing)  :)

Comment: JFTR, my 21-byte answer was 
``+`(\d|\W) | (\W)``
``$1$2``

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES9),  <s>60</s>  43 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/(?<![a-z_] *) | (?=\W)/gi,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NboMwEITvfooJUmS7ARIuvVBAHCr1DXIAFBxiKJVlIxPl0L9Xp4YcmkaqVzurGWk@yW/iIsbG9sM50OYkpzaZxiQdQysHJRrJtix7WhUieD9UeOD4BMuScs@3Xe9TyqfG6NEoGSrTsZbVg@31GQzei1TK@Ngbq04rD5zIi1DMW5QuWtZRWXPKPU4OQALQ61kDFoiBK8uFaxcd6F3mIlIgao11ttewQneSRTsfj/ARRBzzq2qODWipKSckd/iC7qhPc7cZrWKShw7wLJpXJpCk@LXH2X4Q4PaDbHQEMQPdbHBc2MB3utiWjZzH/1duO38rX06mHw)

Comment: I think porting @Abigail's Perl answer saves you a byte, even after using `[^\d\W]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 48 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?<![a-zA-Z_] *) | (?=\\W)","")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLbsIwELz7KwZLKDZKLHLhwktcql564oDUEIEbEmRq4sh2kGjLt6cm6amXHe3s7OzjIm8yuZw@O3VtjPW4hFy0XmlRtXXhlanFZE4KLZ3Dm1Q1vgnQtB9aFXBe@gA3o064hhrbeqvqc5ZD2rPjvRR4@fNZDNV4gBUqLDuXrJywZaNlUW60ZpStF6NMJl@b5P2QY8LxA7Ze7vc7TmNKeTfvLbd358urMK0XTTDzumaVkE2j7@w5OZvmnD@VD/Loul4BBvpaam1i7IzVpxEFJ@VNhpF9jPp4TI884pSTA7AEogHGgAXm4ezeKZDjQB2if1ygSIa0Mjak4VFW1ueSpdMYM8RIUv7cHDkZOtLZLw)

Port of [Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204888/16236).

Answer (score 3):

## perl -p, <strike>24</strike> <strike>27</strike> 26 bytes

```
s/([_\pL] ) +(?=\w)| /$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCoMwAET3fMU1VJIUxWaoS5GuHbp3UFGhUYSQhCjt0m9vmurWG@64B3dOeX0KYc551dbu1kDgwC9l/RJv5HuZjyE4P5kFHPSqtLYp7tbrx45CEPXsNaers9U72QkmqCAtUAJsiwTwwBnYniJMImrZH4uIVJCD9bFOBnHVm1FxeUxRIEUmBX5qyLaRxce6ZbJmDpn7Ag)

This replaces any letter or underscore + space combo, which is followed by letter, digit or underscore, by itself, and removes any other space. In effect, it keeps any space which is proceeded by a letter or an underscore, and is followed by a letter, digit or underscore, and removes any other space. The `(?=\w)` is a lookahead, and won't be consumed by the matcher; this makes cases like `_ _ _ _ _` keep all the spaces.

This will not work correctly for input containing characters outside of the ASCII range.

Comment: This seems to break if you add a few extra spaces between`in` and `range` in the 4th test case

Comment: Indeed. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Can't you just use a space instead of `\s`?

Comment: Of course. I probably just wrote `\s*` out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
≔ωη≔ωζＦθ≡ι ≔ηζ«×ζ№⁺_⭆⁶²⍘κφιι≔ωζ≔× №⁺_α↥ιη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/BaoNAFDzXrxg8vYUNND140FObcyHQ5FRKWMyqjxq1u5pASr59@9RKKL0Mb94bZubllXF5a@oQnr3nsqGLRqWy6M6uworWgb4U/IX7vAKxwneUG28RI07xK65m8dEWZqj7VCQPW8dNTzs@WU9XjU07CN3Wg6f4EGu89XIvX01HyZPGixjOG/rUKJRSGiyYLT48jn@bLXSOkDb/Q4zY7LvOurEw8WQ7vniLbiEA78AaGD/EAeAGcKYpLUByeAQ0kEy4moQK@ACisDrXPw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ωη
```

Set `h` to the empty string. This variable is a space if the last non-space character was a letter.

```
≔ωζ
```

Set `z` to the empty string. This variable is a space if the last character was a space and the last non-space character was a letter.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over the characters of the input.

```
≡ι ≔ηζ«
```

If the current character is a space then copy `h` to `z`, otherwise:

```
×ζ№⁺_⭆⁶²⍘κφι
```

If the current character is a letter or digit then output `z`.

```
ι
```

Output the current character.

```
≔ωζ
```

Set `z` to the empty string.

```
≔× №⁺_α↥ιη
```

Set `h` to a space if the current character is a letter, otherwise set it to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, 285 bytes

```
>~:1+!#@_11g\v>>,>>>>0>11p
v #          <>  ^
>:" "-#v_ \1` |
v      <      >      2^
>:"/"`#v_>    >^
v      <
>:"9"`#v_ \2- |
v      <      >" ",,^
>:"@"`#v_^
v      <      >    >,1^
>:"Z"`#v_ >\2-|
v      <      >" ",^
>:"_"-#v_ ^
v      <
>:"`"`#v_^
v      <
>:"z"`#v_ ^
       > ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBasMwDIbvfoq/DiUxc1jVQ6HtJnrcGwy2LHbH0lIISTFbDmPs1TPVZoV11UHCv359Evi12X10@2Yc@XtFN5Ns44j21cBsWWLGREc1IMM57hioFa80dJkNDhV5fIklNVPhVObRd6u9@KLE9dl46ixjB9W8/E8QvLVxfhNd9bUVbClanhKIhXQVFE0u3fv3BH8BP2mfiVYr/K6qx/EYDt07CuiHpm17i8c@tG8TDaOaYdsWOuY8Zk/e5EYb5YB7IE9lCgRgDSSSiFORXH6hiaSeQbs@yPPQyfqwlf8paGaxgEVJJh71Aqg0RYsf)

This is a simple statement machine, using a single 3 valued state (written to position `(1,1)`). The state is `1` if the previous character was a letter or underscore, `2` if the previous character was a space, and the last non-space character was a letter or underscore, and `0` otherwise.

The program reads one character at a time, ending the program if there is no more input; the read character is pushed on the stack. We then push the current state on the stack, and swap the two elements on the stack. We go through a bunch of if/then/else statements, to find out what kind of character we have (digit, letter or underscore, space, other symbol). If the current character is a digit, letter or underscore, and the current state is `2`, we print a space. We then print the current character, unless that character is a space. Finally, we push the new state on the stack, which we then store on position `(1,1)`, and we enter the loop again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
eþØW,ØD¤
+⁹n⁶¤Tị
Ñ>/ŻçµÑSḊç
```

A full program which accepts a Python formatted string of Python code which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/18L7DM8J1Ds9wObSES/tR4868R43bDi0Jebi7m@vwRDv9o7sPLz@09fDE4Ic7ug4v////v7q6eryCgq2CApRSVVAoUlCwVlAoKMrMK1EACqoCheLV0cRAQurqAA)** (Do note that Jelly evaluates its arguments as Python *before* using them.)

#### How?

```
eþØW,ØD¤   - Link 1: list of characters, A          e.g. "_ 5 ;"
       ¤   - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  ØW       -   word characters                           "A..Za..z0...9_"
     ØD    -   digit characters                          "0...9"
    ,      -   pair                                      ["A..Za..z0...9_, "0...9"]
 þ         - outer product using:
e          -   exists in?                                [[1,0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0]]

+⁹n⁶¤Tị    - Link 2: list of integers, X; list of characters, Y
    ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 ⁹         -   chain's right argument, Y
   ⁶       -   the space character
  n        -   not equal? (vectorises)
+          - add (to X)
     T     - truthy (non-zero) indices
      ị    - index into (Y)

Ñ>/ŻçµÑSḊç - Main Link: list of characters, S
Ñ          - call next Link as a monad -> Link_1(S)
  /        - reduce by:
 >         -   is greater than (gives 1s where letters are, 0s elsewhere)
   Ż       - prepend a zero
    ç      - call last Link as a dyad -> Link_2(that, S)
     µ     - start a new monadic Link:  (call that R)
      Ñ    - call next Link as a monad -> Link_1(R)
       S   - sum (gives 1s at letters, 2s at digits, 0s elsewhere)
        Ḋ  - dequeue
         ç - call last Link as a dyad -> Link_2(that, R)
           - implicit print
```

First removes spaces which do not directly follow letters, then removes remaining spaces which are not directly before letters or digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r' +(?=\W)|(?<![a-zA-Z_]) +','',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFda8IwFH3vr7gGyk0wHescDnSZ7GGwfyDMSq2aukJtSxqH0/nbu6Tp3Afbw0JI7j2553AOqV71c1kMmlRETZ5sl@sE6pGSF/VuSRVCn05ENGVvdHLbmyXB4T54iucM@sgRec28bFuVSoOSjZa1rkEA9RCxUlmhgQJ5lHlecpiWKl/3CDDzxu2AfElyStrT1YtwwZCR80AMRgu6ywdQAGMAp2tA30Ax/sAs1NFnEKalMmhWgEqKjaThJYchcAhCBnbNP0YdPxy2PfPk/lsI2kXoEvwjgDDbV@POnu/HeK4/bf7icsiNxb/cKWtuh9Hu6uZ6hRxcGQ6QeVZJc2m1DllF2//gIPds5Nm89m9SqlnbuGgpkqM@EQjugBxrUxzVrBZCzk/oxrLU0HoCpJP4ynzYV3Kls2IzMlx5Isiadw)

Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204888/9481).